# How to excute the custom code after sign in device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, device

I need to code some business logic after successfully sign-in through device. Is possible to write helper methods after sign-in in application_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you mean Devise.  Devise is built on top of Warden, which offers a number of call-backs:  http://rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/master/Warden/Hooks

Probably what you want is `after_authentication`.